# Style line/fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-2.18

I wonder if there is a way to combine fill and line style for a polygon seperately.

[image]

I tried with simple fill + fillstyle or line pattern fill but both resulted in lines without no background coulor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to move the `Line pattern fill` above the `Simple fill` as this controls which order your symbols will be rendered (i.e. those on top will be shown first):

[image: Symbology]