# Using geometry generator to create line hatch fill

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Since QGIS rasterizes any sort of pattern fill, I have been searching for a way to create, through the geometry generator, a line-hatch fill for a polygon. I so far haven't found anything I can easily adapt to the purpose. I found this for a point fill, which is similar to what I'd like for a line-hatch fill: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337774/122005. I don't care about random spacing, at least at this point. All I care about are two parameters: line spacing and angle. Everything I have found is much more involved and I can't pare the code down to just what I need.

Here's an image of what I'm after:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you included an image that approximates what you'd like to create.

Comment: Misunderstood maybe but wondering why you don't use "Line Pattern fill" https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228862/style-line-fill-in-qgis and try to take the geometry generator option instead?

Comment: The problem is that line pattern fills always rasterize when outputting to PDF. That is why I need to use the geometry generator, as symbologies created this way don't rasterise when output to PDF.

Comment: This thread seems to have gotten very little s attention. I’m sure someone out there knows how to do this. Thanks very much to anyone who can help!

Comment: This should help : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311779/creating-line-pattern-fill-using-geometry-generator-pyqgis